# PHP: What is this object type, and how do I add to it without causing warnings

Tags: php, object, spl

I've encountered this here and there, and I always worked around it, but I've just ***gotta*** know.
Is this an array, an object, or ??? (Let's say I got this via `var_export($co)`)

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'name' => 'Acme Anvil Corp.',
))
```

Most importantly, how can I add a value to it?
Let's say I want to add a value, like `$co->owner = 'Wiley Coyote'`. That always throws a warning.

How?
What?

The curiosity is just KILLING me :)

**[EDIT]**
As a clarification, I guess the root of my question would be "How do I add variables to the object without triggering Warnings?"

Here's the warning I always get:

> A PHP Error was encountered 
>   Severity: Warning 
>   Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object

And a `var_dump($co)` yields: (currently done in a loop, if it's pertinent)

```
object(stdClass)#185 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(16) "Acme Anvil Corp."
}
```

**[/EDIT]**

Answer (score 1):

`$co` is object of type `stdClass`. You can create one and add as many properties as you want without any warning:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->prop1 = 'val1';
$obj->prop2 = 3.14;
```

The warning you are facing is most probably `Creating default object from null value`, meaning that you are trying to assign property to uninitialized variable.

You should not try running the code produced by `var_export` for `stdClass` objects, since they don't have method `__setState`.

Comment: The warning I get is a little different and has now been added to the question. Thanks-a-bunch for the help.

Comment: @mOrloff so `$co` is not an object and not null - try `var_dump($co)` before assigning new property to see what type of variable it is.

Comment: It is in the loop, so there can be the iteration when it is not an object. check it with `is_object($co)` before trying to assign new property.

Comment: The loop is not on `$co` itself, but rather on a dataset which includes a Co ID. _Within_ that loop, the ID is used to get the Co name.  This `$co` object is the result of that query. (BTW, I'm using CodeIgniter activerecord).

Comment: I'm just saying that inside this loop `$co` is getting overwritten . It's hard to say anything else without the code that produces this warning.

Comment: K, thanks, I'll see what I can do about scratching together a (simpler) version of the code that I can share. BTW, I checked with `is_object()`, and got `bool(true)` all the way down. Thanks-a-bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about your error - but the stdClass class is a default in built class to PHP.

It's basically an empty object

You should be able to set properties with `$class->foo = 'bar'`

If you're not talking about stdClass - but the fact you're getting an array in var_export - it's simply a representation of the internal object state .

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = 'baz';
}

$foo = new Foo();

var_export($foo);
```

Should give output similar to

```
Foo::__set_state(array(
   'bar' => 'baz',
))
```

The warning you get may be due to the property being protected/private.

`var_dump()` generally tells you about the access modifiers on internal objects better than `var_export()`

Can you clarify what the warning you get is and what the question is regarding, and I'll edit up my answer to make it relevant to what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

`var_export()` prints executable PHP code able to recreate the variable exported.

When encountering objects, they are always exported as a call to their static magic method `__set_state()`. Compared to other magic methods, this method does not really have much magic in it besides the fact that var_export guarantees to create static calls with this method, so it is simply just the agreed upon name for such a method.

The `__set_state()` method of a class should return an instance of the object with all exported properties set to the values given as the array parameter.

Example:

```
class Foo {
  public $bar;

  public static function __set_state($params) {
    $obj = new Foo;
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
      $obj->$key = $value;
    }
    return $obj;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar = "Hello World";
```

var_export($foo);

This prints something like:

```
Foo::__set_state(array('bar' => 'Hello World'));
```

If you execute this and save it to a variable again:

```
$x = Foo::__set_state(array('bar' => 'Hello World'));
```

it will recreate the object with all given properties set.

It does not work with stdClass objects, because they don't have a `__set_state()` method.

See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state for more info.

Update:

This code does not trigger any warnings:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$co = new stdClass();

$co->name = 'Acme Anvil Corp.';

var_export($co);

$co->owner = 'Wiley Coyote';
```

Comment: it's there ... the error is triggered when I try something like `$co->owner = 'Wiley Coyote'` (the warning always references the exact line number of such an assignment). Any other questions/thoughts ??

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce that.